# Django Saving Data into Database

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm having an issue, what I need is to save a part number into a database table. So everytime a user enters the SOSS it should be save in my table. This is my code but is not saving anything, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**manifiestos.html**

```
                                            <form action="{%  url 'manifiestos' %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                                                <p><label for="date"> Date:</label> <input type="text" name="date" value={% now "Y-m-d" %} /> </p>
                                                <p><label for="soss"> SOSS:</label> <input type="text" name="soss" id="soss" /> </p>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                        </form>
```

**models.py**

```
class manifiestos_bts(models.Model):
    soss = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ManifiestosForm(forms.Form):
    soss = forms.CharField()
    date = forms.DateTimeField()
    user = forms.CharField()
```

**html_views**

```
@login_required(login_url='/msr/login')
def manifiestos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ManifiestosForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            soss = request.POST.get('soss', '')
            date = request.POST.get('date', '')
            manifiestos_obj = manifiestos_bts(soss= soss, date= date)
            manifiestos_obj.save()

            return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manifiestos'))
    else:
        form = ManifiestosForm()

    return render(request, 'manifiestos.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^manifiestos$', html_views.manifiestos, name='manifiestos'),
```

Thanks for your time :)
If you need more details just let me know.

Comment: What is the result? and what are you passing for `user`?  and why are you using `request.POST['soss']` when you have `form` already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form.is_valid() will fail because you are not passing user from your template. Either remove it from ManifiestosForm or pass it from manifiestos.html

Comment: so that is why is not passing the data? I should just delete user or add it then? let me give it a try